# Pass job results to other job with Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I make an API call to fetch an email address. On success I'd like to pass this email address to another job. I use **sidekiq** and **sidekiq-batch** gems.

```
class HandleWebhookJob
  def perform
    batch = Sidekiq::Batch.new
    batch.description = "Handling webhook"
    batch.on(:success, HandleWebhookJob::OtherJob, { email: @email })
    batch.jobs do
      @email = GetEmailJob.perform_async # returns email address
    end
  end

  class OtherJob
    def on_success(status, options)
      puts options # no email address here - nil
      # need to pass it to UseEmailJob.perfom_async(options[:email])
    end
  end
end
```

I assume that assigning the result of **GetEmailJob** to **@email** won't work. Can't find an example of how to do this and if it's even possible.

Comment: In this case, is it not a problem you are trying to access `@email` (in the `batch.on` call) before it is assigned?

Comment: Maybe you are right. What is the way to do it?

Comment: Is it an option to have either `GetEmailJob` to start `OtherJob` or define a job `CollectEmailAndStart OtherJob` that will first collect the email and then start the `OtherJob`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you get `jid` in `@email`.
Can you save emails in `GetEmailJob` to some storage (e.g. redis) with `prefix:jid` key and take them from there?

Comment: Sounds like a right way to do it. I have no idea what's jid. Any good resource on the subject?

Comment: Thank you @Stanislav. Eventually, I ended up with the approach you suggested